# Having problems with Vue and images on my modal

Tags: html, forms, vue.js

I have cards that shows the name, description,price and an image, this works but when I press more info I basiclly want to show the same stuff but with more info but the modal doesn't want to show the image, pretty new to vue and such so I have no clue what's wrong:

```
  <div class="container" id="app">
    <div class="row justify-content-center mt-5">
      <div class="card mr-5 mb-5" v-for="product in products" v-bind:key="product.id">
        <div class="card-body">
          <img v-bind:src="product.image" style="height:15rem">
          <h5 class="card-title">{{ product.name }}</h5>
          <p class="card-text">{{ product.description }}</p>
          <p class="card-text"><b>Price: {{ product.price }}</b></p>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal"
            v-on:click="showProductInUpdateForm(product.id)">More Info</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal fade" id="updateModal">
      <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
          <div class="modal-header">
            <h5 class="modal-title">More Info</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>

          <div class="modal-body">
            <form id="formUpdate">
              <img v-bind:src="product.image">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Id">ID</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="updateId" id="updateId" readonly>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Name">Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="updateName" id="updateName" readonly>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Description">Description</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="updateDescription" id="updateDescription" readonly>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label for="Price">Price</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="updatePrice" id="updatePrice" readonly>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                
                <label for="Image">Image</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="updateImage" id="updateImage" readonly>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger float-right" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                <button type="button" class="add-to-cart btn btn-primary float-right" data-dismiss="modal">Add to cart</button>
              </div>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are declaring variable `product` in a `v-for` loop. So `product` can be only accessed inside that loop block.

```html
<div v-for="product in products" v-bind:key="product.id">
  {{product}}
</div>
...
<!-- product is 'undefined' here since it's outside of the v-for loop block -->
<img v-bind:src="product.image">
```

You can store selected item in some global property that can be accessed from everywhere:

```html
<button v-on:click="showProductInUpdateForm(product)">More Info</button>
...
<img v-bind:src="selectedItem.image">
```

```js
data {
  return {
    selectedItem: {}
  }
},
methods: {
  showProductInUpdateForm (product) {
    this.selectedItem = product
    ...
  }
}
```